# Delphi SOAP Client adding items to dynamic array

Tags: arrays, delphi, soap, delphi-xe6

I'm currently developing a client for a SOAP service.

The WSDL import works fine, but I'm facing the problem that I need to add items to a dynamic array.

The declaration in delphi:

```
    Array_Of_attributWS = array of attributWS;

    dienstleistungWS = class(TRemotable)
      private
         [..]
      public
         [..]
      published
        property attributeWS: Array_Of_attributWS
         Index(IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL)read GetattributeWS
         write SetattributeWS stored attributeWS_Specified;
```

I want to add an item to attributeWS from an other unit.
To add an item I use this code:

```
    SetLength(dynArray, Length(dynArray)+1);
    dynArray[High(dynArray)] := item;
```

But it wont let me, I get the following error: 
E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter

Is there a way to add an item easy to the dynamic array?
Or is there a way to cast the array to a list so that I can just do .Append(item)?

Delphi Version XE6
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `SetattributeWS` implementation you will see it simply gets your *dynamic array* as a `const` parameter, stores it and marks an internal boolean variable as true (indicating the parameter has been informed).

The `const` part is the one that causes the *E2197* error you are seeing.

The best option is to use a local `dynamic array` variable of the same type and then:

1. set its length to the actual length of `attributeWS` + 1.
2. copy the original items from `attributeWS` to the local variable, and then add the new item.
3. assign this variable to the `attributeWS` property.

Actually, it would be better to not assign the dynamic array to the *request property* until you have it filled with all the necessary elements, but that may depend on your needs.